# Display live git-clone progress using dialog

Tags: bash, git, dialog

I've been trying to get git-clone to provide output to a textbox in dialog. I tried something like this:

```
git clone github.com/CrazyWillBear/yes-replacement 2> /tmp/clone.log &
dialog --title "Cloning repo..." --textbox /tmp/clone.log 50 100
```

It doesn't work and usually displays nothing, writes to the terminal, or just the first line of the output. A loop doesn't work either, it creates some really funky problems.

The result I'm trying to get is this but with the entire output instead of just the first line: [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pyqar.png)

Comment: Please add sample input of your `git` command (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Answer (score 0):

Use tee to write the output to a file, then use the tailbox feature on dialog to read it live.

```
git clone https://github.com/CrazyWillBear/pig --progress 2>&1 | tee -a /tmp/clone.$$ &> /dev/null &
dialog --title "Progress" --tailbox /tmp/clone.$$ 50 100
```